# disjoint subsets proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Context: let $x \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$. Set $S_{x} = \{ i \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0} | 0 \leq i < x \}$ for each $x \in \mathbb{N}$. For $x \in \mathbb{N}$, let the set of disjoint subset pairs of $S_x$ be $PR_{x} = \{ (Q,W) | Q,W \subseteq S_x, Q \cap W = \emptyset \}$.

For understanding purposes can someone check these, (keep in mind order matters for this case):

Let $x = 0$. then $PR_{x} = \{ \emptyset \}$ (or would it be $\{ \{ \{ \}, \{ \} \} \}$)?

Let $x = 1$. Then $PR_{x}=  \{ \{ \}, \{ 0 \}, \{ \{ \},0 \}, \{0, \{ \} \} \}$.

Let $x = 2$. Then $PR_{x}= \{ \{ \}, \{ 0 \}, \{1 \}, \{1,0 \}, \{0,1 \},  \{ \{ \},0,1 \}, \{ \{ \},1,0 \}, \{1,0, \{ \} \}, \{0,1 \{ \} \}, \{1, \{ \},0 \}  \{0, \{ \},1 \}$.

Am I missing some or not understand the $\{ \}$?

Also, what would be a formula then to check if I have included all elements? That would likely help a lot.

Comment: Your definition of $PR_x$ has **ordered** pairs as elements. Then for $x=1$ we get $PR_1=\{\langle\{\},\{\}\rangle,\langle\{\},\{0\}\rangle,\langle\{0\},\{\}\rangle\}$ where $\langle a,b\rangle$ abbreviates $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: Oh my bad... then x=1 should be different also.. being {[{},{}], [{},{0}],[{0},{}],[{},{1}],[{1},{}], [{1},{0}], [{0},{1}], [{}, {0,1}], [{}, {1,0}], [ {1,0},{}]... but would it be different from[{0,1},{}] because the order is inside the element? how many are there total for x=1

Comment: If $a\neq b$ then $\langle a,b\rangle\neq\langle b,a\rangle$. This in contrast with $\{a,b\}=\{b,a\}$.

Comment: I count $9$ ordered pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ with $a,b\subseteq S_2$ and $a\cap b=\varnothing$

Comment: so did i get them all without including [{}, {1,0}]?

Comment: Yes. In your list $\langle\{\},\{1,0\}\rangle$ was written twice. Apart from that the list is okay. If you take away the duplicate then $9$ pairs are left.

Comment: i see thanks! Can you also help me come up with a formula to check? i see 1,3 9, ... is it simply 3^x

Comment: Yes, it is $3^x$. For every element in $S_x$ there is a choice out of $3$: it will land up in $Q$, $W$ or $S_x-(Q\cup W)$. That gives $3^x$ possibilities in total. These possibilities correspond one-to-one with elements in $PR_x$.

Comment: you could prove this formula with induction right?(for the naturals) let the base case be 0(considering the case when 0 is indeed a natural) then the cardinality of $PR_{0}$ is 1 and $3^0$ is also one. then how would you complete the inductive step? of (induction on k) $PR_{k+1}$ = $3^{k+1}$

Comment: As often you can indeed prove it by induction, but I see no profit in that. What I said in my former comment is a full proof allready.

Comment: I see your comment is a full proof, but for the sake of induction practice (for myself) does the above look valid? would you maybe have to sub in your hypothesis PR_{K}=3^{k}? I am confused on where to go...

Comment: Inductionhypothese: the cardinality of $PR_x$ is $3^x$. On base of that it must be shown that the cardinality of $PR_{x+1}$ is $3^{x+1}$. Well, every element $(Q,W)$ of $PR_x$ induces $3$ elements of $PR_{x+1}$ which are $(Q,W)$, $(Q\cup\{x\},W)$ and $(Q,W\cup\{x\})$. So the total number of elements will be multiplied by factor $3$ (so the cardinality of $PR_{x+1}$ will be $3.3^x=3^{x+1}$).

Comment: can you further show how 3.3^x=3^x+1... Like I agree but want to fully understand it.  Also what do you mean induces 3 elements.. again I agree but want to fully understand ?

Comment: $3.3^x=3^1.3^{x}=3^{x+1}$ is a direct application of the general rule $b^n.b^m=b^{n+m}$. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) for further explanation. "Induces" can be replaced by "corresponds with". Here I stop with further explanation. If your understanding is not full yet, then have a careful look at small cases ($x=1,2,3,4,\dots$) and try to grasp what is going on. I cannot let your understanding grow by repeating the same in other words. Good luck with your math study.

Comment: oh wait are you using decimal to denote multiplication? or is that a decimal? I  have never seen it before thats why.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion. In my comment $.$ stands for multiplication.